# Unable to UNLOAD the information schema from Redshift to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to UNLOAD the information schema from Redshift to S3?
Getting following error when trying to UNLOAD Information schema

*ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.*

Following is the query I am using for unloading:

```
UNLOAD ('select table_schema,
      table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema not in (\'information_schema\', \'pg_catalog\')
     and table_type = \'BASE TABLE\'
order by table_schema,
        table_name;')
TO 's3://xxx/'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxx';
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message is often generated when leader-node-only data needs to be sent to compute nodes and there is no path for data to flow in this direction during a query.  Typically happens when you try to join some system tables with user data.  Now I've never generated this error the way you have but expect this is what is going on because UNLOAD works in parallel through all the compute nodes.

This may just work if you change your UNLOAD to PARALLEL OFF which will write the data to S3 through the leader node.  Since the data doesn't have to go to compute nodes it could get you past this error.

If not there are ways to select the data from these system tables into a cursor and then read the cursor into a temp table.  Then you could unload the temp table.  I can point you to a process to do this if needed.

Comment: That's very interesting (PARALLEL OFF writes are from leader-node only).  Thanks!

Comment: Just remember that this can also be an anti-pattern.  Too much unload data flowing through the leader node can significantly impact leader node performance and detract from its other important functions (query compile and result delivery).

Comment: I was thinking more about the cases where you handle leader-node only data types.  Ipso facto, you can't recruit the worker nodes, so you're not loosing performance you'd otherwise have, but for the system tables where you can't use UNLOAD or INSERT, and have to actually have an external entity issue a SELECT, capture the rows, and issue an INSERT, this would on the face of it solve that problem.  Having said that, I'm wondering what COPY would emit for say an ACLitem[].  Presumably the string representation (which is what SELECTT receives.)

Comment: COPY always reads data into compute node(s) and doesn't support non-compute node data types.  This error is produced whenever a leader only table data is needed on a compute node, even if the data types are supported.  If you need to insert from these tables you will need to unload and copy OR select into a cursor and read the cursor into another table.

Comment: Sorry - that was a grammatical typo.  I wrote `COPY` when I intended to write `UNLOAD`.